# PowerApps How to get Distinct values of a SharePoint list which is a datasource of dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I am building an app in SharePoint online  using PowerApp, I have a dropdown which its data source is from a SharePoint list, it has duplicate data, so I need to get distinct values for the dropdown.

I check PowerApps documentation it has a formula like bellow

```
Distinct(Employees, Department)
```

It works if your data connection is from Excel, but if your data connection is from a SharePoint list, I could not figure it out, any help is appreciated

Comment: In my sharepoint list, I have more than 1500 records. The distinct function only pics up one entry. For Example, 1st 900 records are A
2nd 200 Records are B
3rd 100 Records are C It only shows "A" in my dropdown list and no other option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried it here and the Distinct function did the job.

`Distinct(ListName,ColumnName)`

If your list is too large it could take some time to remove the duplicates

[image: No Distinct]

[image: With Distinct]

Comment: Thanks, yeah actually my list was too long, and I figured it out, thanks